# Check if external URL contains string

Tags: jquery, html

I was trying to add a feature on my site where I could have a button & it will try to look up for a string from an external URL/different website.

I have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(document.URL("URL").contains('Limit reached') {
   alert("msghere");
else
   alert("msghere");
}
```

});

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you saying you want to examine the URL itself, or the content of the page/resource it refers to?

Comment: Yes, kind of like "detect" the external URL & see if the specified string(s) is/are present on that given time(when button is clicked) I don't even know how to trigger it using the button. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not my own URL where I put the button but an external URL.

Comment: You may want to change your alert statements to say something different.  Otherwise, regardless of the URL it will respond with `msghere`.

Comment: Ofc, it's gonna be different, I just shortened the msg coz it's diff in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Space is represented as %20 in a url.  Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(document.URL("URL").contains('Limit%20reached') {
     alert("found");
  else
     alert("not found");
  }
```

Comment: the URL I'm using shouldn't have space, but the string(s) I'm trying to look for has 1 "Limit reached"

Comment: Url's cannot have spaces.  Therefore space is represented in a url as %20.  So the url might be something like http://foo.com?q=limit%20reached and you will need to search for the string "limit%20reached"